# How do I resolve a 'Unsupported value for canned acl 'private' error' on Backblaze B2 S3 Compatible API?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, backblaze

After getting help with the issue in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76163129/how-do-i-resolve-this-backblaze-b2-s3-compatible-api-error), I'm getting another error despite successfully uploading the image which I can see on my Backblaze dashboard and within my app.

```
Unable to write file at location: profile-photos/0Oafj0VpwBbrMtvgLEnBmGl3UsL4rrUaD7HLzRDA.jpg. 
Error executing "PutObject" on "https://xxx.s3.us-west-004.backblazeb2.com/profile-photos/0Oafj0VpwBbrMtvgLEnBmGl3UsL4rrUaD7HLzRDA.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://xxx.s3.us-west-004.backblazeb2.com/profile-photos/0Oafj0VpwBbrMtvgLEnBmGl3UsL4rrUaD7HLzRDA.jpg` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
  <Error> 
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code> 
    <Message>Unsupporte (truncated...) 
InvalidArgument (client): Unsupported value for canned acl 'private' - 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<Error> 
  <Code>InvalidArgument</Code> 
  <Message>Unsupported value for canned acl 'private'</Message> 
</Error>
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the differences between Backblaze B2's S3-compatible API and Amazon S3. Backblaze B2 controls visibility at the bucket, rather than the object, level, and you have two choices: `private` or `public-read` (shown as just 'public' in the Backblaze web UI). If you specify an ACL when you put an object in a bucket, it **must** match the ACL of the bucket. [Here is the relevant section of the docs](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/s3_compatible_api.html#:%7E:text=Copy%20(PUT)-,ACLs,-The%20Backblaze%20S3).

It looks like Laravel is trying to create a private object in a public-read bucket, so B2 is returning the `Unsupported value` error.

There are two ways to fix this. Either:

- Change the visibility of your bucket from `public-read` to `private` (**Bucket Settings** in the web UI), or
- Configure Laravel to create objects with the `public-read` canned ACL.

[From this discussion at Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/s3-and-visibility), it looks like you can set the default visibility in the s3 config in `config/filesystems.php`. If you set `public` here, it is mapped to `public-read` by the S3 driver.

```php
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => 'your-key',
            'secret' => 'your-secret',
            'region' => 'your-region',
            'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```